# Problemas con variables y paso de parametros en Middleware Express NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, funciones, express

tengo la siguiente peticion desde el front:

```
let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/getJson?consulta=EmbarqueDetalle");
```

y en el back la recibo con express y hago una consulta a sql server de la siguiente manera:

```
app.get('/getJson', function(req, res){
  let consulta = req.query.consulta; //consulta = EmbarqueDetalle

  getJson(consulta)
  .then(datos => {
    let resultado =  datos.recordset[0].consulta; //Si pongo EmbarqueDetalle si funciona
                                                  //como hacer que tome el valor de consulta?
    res.json(resultado)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(`Hubo un error`);
  });
})

app.listen(3000)

console.log('Server on port 3000')



async function getJson(parametro) { //porque si se ejecuta la funcion llamada
  try {                             //pero no se pasa el parametro?
      await sql.connect(config);
      let db = new sql.Request();
      let consulta = consultas.EmbarqueDetalle;
      let datos = await db.query(consulta);
      return datos;
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      throw err;
  }
}

let consultas = {
  "EmbarqueDetalle":"select dbo.Embarques(default) as EmbarqueDetalle"
}
```

La pregunta es primero: como puedo usar el valor de la variable en el recordeset? yo se que con el recordset estoy accediendo al valor de la columna pero no se como usar una variable en vez del valor explicito.
Y segundo: porque la funcion getJson() llamada desde el middleware si se ejecuta pero no recibe el parametro?

Comment: ¿Puede especificar un poco más qué es lo que sucede con el segundo problema que tienes?

Comment: Quiero mandar el parametro para que en vez de: let consulta = consultas.EmbarqueDetalle pueda usar: let consulta = consultas.parametro asi con la misma func puedo hacer diferentes consultas. El tema es que la funcion se ejecuta pero el parametro esta grisado, no lo recibe

Comment: Creo que pude entender a lo que te refieres, te actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: era por la misma situacion que la pregunta 1, estaba tratando de acceder a una propiedad de objeto con la variable y por no estar entre corchetes me estaba dando dolores de cabeza. No se donde estaba cuando en el curso de js explicaron eso, jaja. Muchisimas gracias otra vez @FranAcuna

Comment: Con mucho gusto, te recomiendo siempre consultar [la documentación en Español](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) es muy clara, directa al grano y con ejemplos sencillos. El complemento ideal para cualquier tutorial que estés haciendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera en que estás accediendo las propiedades de tu objeto es errónea, cuando haces:

```
let resultado =  datos.recordset[0].consulta;
```

Estás accediendo la propiedad llamada `consulta` (cuándo en realidad quieres `EmbarqueDetalle`) del primer elemento del array de `recordset`. Si quieres acceder las propiedades de un objeto por medio del contenido de una variable `string`, deberías de hacer:

```
let resultado =  datos.recordset[0][consulta];
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional para ejemplificar:

```js
const datos ={
  EmbarqueDetalle : "Soy un detalle del embarque"
 }
 
const consulta = "EmbarqueDetalle";

console.log(`datos.consulta = ${datos.consulta}`);
console.log(`datos[consulta] = ${datos[consulta]}`);
```

Con respecto a tú segundo problema:

> el tema es que la funcion se ejecuta pero el parametro esta grisado,
> no lo recibe

El parámetro esta "grisado" porque tu IDE te está indicando que ese parámetro de entrada no está siendo utilizado en tu función, y es cierto, nunca utilizas dicho parámetro, por lo que me describes supongo que quieres hacer:

```
let consulta = consultas[parametro];
```

¡Espero que esto te sea de utilidad!

Comment: Claro!! Por eso preguntaba como usar una variable para acceder a una propiedad. No sabia lo de los corchetes. Muchisimas gracias @FranAcuna